Texture bug Bevel


What is this weird shining on my Object. I beveled it and now this is there. Everything has the same texture.
How do i get it away?

check your face orientation

Check for internal faces left behind by a Mirror ..

also try a M > Merge by Distance

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

For some reason the split normals (the normals that determine the shading) are messed up on this part, go into the Data panel > Geometry Data and click on Clear Custom Split Normals Data:

